# How can we exclude our own app (ios) from appearing in share sheet?

Tags: react-native, mobile-development, share-extension, ios-sharesheet, react-native-share

I am using `react-native-share` to share images from my app to an other app. It is working fine but my own app is appearing in the share sheet. How can I exclude my app so that it does not appear in share the sheet.

i have used `excludedActivityTypes:["com.org.myappIdentifier"]` prop as well but it is not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference follow this link:

https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2016/hiding-action-share-extensions-in-your-own-apps/

In node_modules/react-native-share/ios/RNShare.mm
add this function at top and replace Your share extension target with your target.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ActionExtensionBlockerItem : NSObject<UIActivityItemSource>

@end

@implementation ActionExtensionBlockerItem

- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType:(UIActivityType)activityType {
    return @"Your share extension target ";
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(UIActivityType)activityType {
    // Returning an NSObject here is safest, because otherwise it is possible for the activity item to actually be shared!
    return [NSObject new];
}

- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(UIActivityType)activityType {
    return @"";
}

- (UIImage *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController thumbnailImageForActivityType:(UIActivityType)activityType suggestedSize:(CGSize)size {
    return nil;
}

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
    return @"";
}

@end
```

and then in open method add these lines of code.

```
ActionExtensionBlockerItem *blockerItem = [ActionExtensionBlockerItem new];

// Add the blockerItem to your existing array of items
[items addObject:blockerItem];
```

This will hopefully fix your issue.